# C# optimization expression folding observations

Tags: c#, optimization, expression, folding

I've been a C++ developer for many years and switched to C# some time ago. Recently I started playing with dotPeek to recover some old code. I was surprised to see the code that came out of the decompiler looked so unoptimized. I started writing some code expecting the compiler to do expression folding and was astonished with the results. I wanted to share my observations and see what comments you may have as to why I'm seeing the results I'm seeing.

Compiler option Optimized on. .NET version 4.5.

First I'll share results I expected:

```
Console.Write(1 + 1 + 1);  turned into Console.Write(3);  
Console.Write ("a" + "b" + "c"); turned into Console.Write("abc");
```

Now here is where I was surprised:

```
string a = "aaaaa";
string b = "aaaaa";

Console.Write(b + a);
```

I expected the compiler to fold this expression to: output.Write("aaaaaaaaaa"); or at least output.Write(a+a); It did neither. It preserved the original. Surprised the compiler didn't notice the duplicate text and reference a single copy of it twice or fold the constants together. You may argue that I didn't add 'const'. (When I did that, the compiler did fold the expressions and removed the constants altogether). The variables are local and only used in this one place. The compiler should have noticed this and properly folded the expressions together without the 'const' property.

I did exactly the same experiment with int. The outcome was almost the same: when I used const int, it folded properly. When I removed the 'const' attribute

```
int c = 1, d = 1, e = 1;
Console.Write(c + d + e);
```

Resulted in:

```
int num1 = 1;
int num2 = 1;
int num3 = 1;
int num4 = num2;
Console.Write(num1 + num4 + num3);
```

This is totally bazar. I can't explain this one. The compiler wrote worse code.
C++ compilers seem to do a lot better when it comes to expression folding.

Comment: You're not factoring in the JIT compiler. What gets produced from  .NET assembly is IL which is further compiled into native assembly as and when each method is hit. This is where the 'true' optimization occurs and where it would likely correctly fold the variables.

Comment: That does look bizarre. Is there any code you're not showing us in the int case?

Comment: How did you go about getting that final piece of code there?

Comment: prefix the string declarations with `const`, should do it. A variable is is not considered constant, where as the 'inline' string constants are.

Comment: I'm pretty sure dotPeek produced an incorrect mapping back from IL in that final example. Not "horribly wrong", just not exactly what the code was doing. Can you share the produced IL code?

Comment: Also, same for the `int`. But the SSA form it gives you is optimal for the JIT to deal with. Also looks like DEBUG output. Release mode will eliminate the temporaries, but there is hardly any cost to them at runtime.

Comment: I agree with leppie.  Optimizing will not eliminate variables.

Comment: To produce the output, I wrote a simple class assembly using the example code I posted. I then dropped the DLL output onto dotPeek and the resulting decompiled code is what I put in the message.